# How do I downgrade to a previous version of Edge Browser

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-edge

We are testing an web app and for that we need to test it on Edge V12 or V13. We spent considerable time to find a way to do this, but the only suggestion we are getting online is on downgrading Edge to IE. Is there a way to downgrade from current version of Edge (v16) to V13?

Comment: I also need to test on a specific Edge version.  Did you find a solution?  Is it even possible to install an old version of windows 10 and manage the update process forward to a particular os version?  This sounds problematic and time consuming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at creating virtual machines of each environment you want to test with.

So install early Windows 10 into a VM. Register it etc...

Copy VM, boot and update to next service pack / Edge release.

Repeat for next service pack on new VM etc...